# How to have regions listen to event triggered on layout in Marionette?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Let's say I have a layout:

`layout = Marionette.LayoutView`

Inside I have a region with a collection view.

```
collectionView = Marionette.CollectionView
layout.collectionRegion.show(collectionView)
```

If I trigger an event on the `layout`, how can I have the collection view listen to it? eg.

```
collectionView.on("get:to:collection:view")
layout.trigger("get:to:collection:view")
// IN THIS CASE THE COLLECTION VIEW WILL NOT RECEIVE THE EVENT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently triggering an event on the `layout` and listening for events on the `collectionView`. You should just trigger the event on the collectionView itself:

```
collectionView.trigger('some:event');

// In the collection view
this.listenTo(this, 'some:event', callback);
```

If you want the collection view to listen to events on the layout you either have to pass the layout into the collection view, or call the callbacks on the collection view from the layout. It's better if the `collectionView` knows nothing about the `layout`, and the `layout` pushes all the communication downwards, like I've demonstrated above.